# Improvement of State Machine implemented in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, state-machine

I am working on an implementation of a state machine in scala.

The original version is written in python, therefore I have a lot of if /else clauses in the code.

The state machine itself, has more values than the state. And the state itself depends on those values.

The states of the object will be stored in a database every time when the state changes.

To update the state, the state machine has an update method, to do the transitions.

The code example is very basic, my question is regarding the nesting of my if statement in the pattern matching approach. Is there a cleaner way in scala to achieve this? I used an immutable way of implementing it.

```
trait State
case object Initial extends State
case object State1 extends State
case object State2 extends State        

case class StateMachine (
                              id: Int,
                              currentState: State = Initial,
                              previousState: Option[State] = None,
                              value1: Int = 0,
                              value2: Int = 0,
                              value3: Int = 0
                            ) {



    def update(val1: Int, val2: Int, val3: Int): StateMachine = {

    val newStateMachine: StateMachine = (val1, val2) match {

      case (1, 1 ) => {

        val tempVal3 = val1 + val2

        if (val3 != 0 && val3 <= 100) {
          this.copy(currentState = State1, value1 = val1, value2 = val2, value3 = val3)
        } else if (val3 > 100) {
          this.copy(currentState = State2,value1 = val1, value2 = val2, value3 = val3 - tempVal3)
        }
        else {
          this.copy(value3 = tempVal3)
        }
      }

      case (2, _) if (val3 != 0 && val3 <= 100) => {
        if (val3 != 0 && val3 <= 50) {
          this.copy(currentState = State1, value1 = val1, value2 = val2, value3 = val3)
        }
        else {
          this.copy(value3 = 0)
        }
      }

      case _ => this
    }

    newStateMachine
  }
}
```

Comment: this code is hard to read. It’s probably better to divide `update` into several subfunctions, and then use a combination of them. Give each function a good name. Also you should avoid names like `x1`, `x2` in most cases.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Names like x1 x2 are only used for this example. So if I extract the if statements within the case to an additional method, can I pass the current instance of the state-machine?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. For starters, `State1` and `State2` are not even defined. There is no description of what `State` might be, etc. Since this is ultimately a code cleanup question, you should create a [mcve] in this case, otherwise suggestions cannot be that useful.

Comment: Some basic pointers:  remove braces after `=>` in case clauses; cases are evaluated from top to bottom so if you cover a case, you don't need to check for it again in a lower line of code; `val3` can also be part of the match.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit hasty and wrote my question without reading the whole HowTo. I've added the trait State and an implementation of it.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. After that I recognised, that my example was a bad one. I have to rethink it and will come back with a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Programming a full feldged State Machine is a hard task and from what I read in your question, there is already a Scala Framework does exactly what you want

[Akka Finite State Machine ( FSM )](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fsm.html)

I strongly advice to check it.

Naturally what you will read there snippets about a Hello World, if you want to see how a full fledged solution should look like, I wrote blogs [Akka FSM Implementation Example](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/), [Model Driven Finite State Machine](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/model-driven-akka-finite-state-machine-fsm/) about it you can find the implementation details there.